# Render view and new JSON response in symfony controller

Tags: json, symfony, controller, twig

I'm having an issue rendering a Twig view and a JSON response, I need to call the twig view and pass it a new Json response with a variable as parameter. The output error is the following "Notice: Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response could not be converted to int
"
Here is the code

```
        $resultado = array('mes1_local' => $mes1_local, 'mes2_local' => $mes2_local, 'mes3_local' => $mes3_local, 'mes1_online' => $mes1_online, 'mes2_online' => $mes2_online, 'mes3_online' => $mes3_online, 'contador_pedido_local' => $contador_pedido_local, 'contador_pedido_online' => $contador_pedido_online, 'contador_total' => $contador_total, 'contador_usuarios' => $contador_usuarios);
       return new JsonResponse($resultado, $this->render('others/adminlte.html.twig'));
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a rendered Twig template or a JSON response? What are the contents of `others/adminlte.html.twig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Json Response signature is

```
__construct(mixed $data = null, int $status = 200, array $headers = array(), bool $json = false)
```

You are trying to give the twig to the status parameter.

You can avoid this silly error by using a good IDE

To give additional data to your response you could structure your array data returned

```
   return new JsonResponse([
       'someData' => $resultado, 
       'html' => $this->render('others/adminlte.html.twig')
   );
```

Comment: I figured out the error about "convert the object to int" was about the response, but I didn't know how to render a view and pass a json parameter in the same response as well. I'm using PHPStorm btw. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @LeandroGabrielli Updated my answer to get both. We can't know what you know or not from your question, that's why it is a fast answer

Answer (score 5):

Like @goto's answer, but it won't works, cause you need to use `renderView` instead of `render`:

```
    return new JsonResponse([
        'things' => $thingsArray,
        'anotherVariable' => $simpleVariable,
        'html' => $this->renderView('others/adminlte.html.twig', []/* template parameters goes here */),
    ]);
```

Comment: After hours of Googling, this (renderView) resolved all my issues! I can't thank you enough